# Error inflating class com.nirhart.parallaxscroll.views.ParallaxScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, parallax

I'm working on a project in which I'm trying to use ParallaxScrollview to get some decent UI/UX effects and it's crashing with Binary XML inflation error. I'm looking for some help and adding these texts to avoid lack of details error. Any sort of help is appreciated.  Here are the details :

servicedetails_fraglayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.nirhart.parallaxscroll.views.ParallaxScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:parallax_factor="1">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:id="@+id/servicetype_imageview"
            android:src="@drawable/bgm_crop"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
            android:text="@string/service_rating"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/accent_red"
            android:id="@+id/serviceratings_textview"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/service_description"
            android:textColor="@color/accent_red"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/serviceratings_textview"
            android:id="@+id/servicedescription_textview"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/location_logo"
            android:layout_below="@id/serviceratings_textview"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/servicedescription_textview"
            android:src="@drawable/place_black_18dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/service_location"
            android:textColor="@color/accent_red"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/location_logo"
            android:layout_below="@id/serviceratings_textview"
            android:id="@+id/servicelocation_textview"/>


    </RelativeLayout>

</com.nirhart.parallaxscroll.views.ParallaxScrollView>
```

Here is the Activity class :

```
package com.customer.xyz.abc.Fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.customer.xyz.abc.Adapters.CategoriesRecyclerAdapter;
import com.customer.xyz.abc.ModelClasses.FetchCategories.AllCategoriesHelper;
import com.customer.xyz.abc.ModelClasses.FetchCategories.CategoryModel;
import com.customer.xyz.abc.ModelClasses.FetchCategories.FetchAllCategories;
import com.customer.xyz.abc.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ServiceDetailsFragment extends Fragment implements FetchAllCategories {


    View serviceView;
    RecyclerView dummyList;
    CategoriesRecyclerAdapter categoriesRecyclerAdapter;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        serviceView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.servicedetails_fraglayout,container,false);

       // dummyList = serviceView.findViewById(R.id.dummy_list);


       // dummyList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        AllCategoriesHelper allCategoriesHelper = new AllCategoriesHelper(getActivity(),this);
        allCategoriesHelper.getAllCategories();
        return serviceView;
    }

    @Override
    public void allCategories(ArrayList<CategoryModel> categoryModels) {

        categoriesRecyclerAdapter = new CategoriesRecyclerAdapter(getActivity(),categoryModels);
       // dummyList.setAdapter(categoriesRecyclerAdapter);
    }
}
```

Here is my log :

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.nirhart.parallaxscroll.views.ParallaxScrollView
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.nirhart.parallaxscroll.views.ParallaxScrollView
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at com.customer.xyz.abc.Fragments.ServiceDetailsFragment.onCreateView(ServiceDetailsFragment.java:31)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2343)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1421)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1752)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1821)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2595)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2382)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2337)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2244)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:702)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1.0"
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:608)
        at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.convertValueToInt(XmlUtils.java:133)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getInt(TypedArray.java:375)
        at com.nirhart.parallaxscroll.views.ParallaxScrollView.init(ParallaxScrollView.java:45)
        at com.nirhart.parallaxscroll.views.ParallaxScrollView.<init>(ParallaxScrollView.java:33)
```

in case if you need my build.gradle details :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.customer.xyz.abc"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you look closely at your logs this is the cause of exception 'Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1.0"'

Comment: I have tried with 1, 1.0 and 1.9 and got same results.

Comment: can you specify  on which line you are getting this error ?

Comment: at com.customer.dealnsum.dealnsum.Fragments.ServiceDetailsFragment.onCreateView(ServiceDetailsFragment.java:31) says error is in  serviceView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.servicedetails_fraglayout,container,false); of the code

Comment: with this message at the top : android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.nirhart.parallaxscroll.views.ParallaxScrollView
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.nirhart.parallaxscroll.views.ParallaxScrollView
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: no not this one I am talking about this error 
'Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1.0"'

Comment: I kindly request you to try this code and suggest me further. because whatever the number im mentioning in app:parallax_factor="1.9" of xml, its being reflected in that error Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1.9"

Comment: let me take a look at it.

Comment: Any updates on this one ??

Comment: I was unable to fix this. I believe there is some issue in the library.

Comment: looks like its not been addressed for a while.  Thanks for trying https://github.com/nirhart/ParallaxScroll/issues/62

Comment: no problem thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

Update your lib version

- from

> implementation 'com.github.nirhart:ParallaxScroll:1.0'

- To

> implementation 'com.github.nirhart:ParallaxScroll:dd53d1f9d1'

this will solve your problem for sure

Comment: Failed to resolve: com.github.nirhart:ParallaxScroll:dd53d1f9d1

Comment: This worked for me because they resolve the bug for Android level 7 or above.

Comment: And this is issue is created at no 63 on github and they resolved it

Comment: if you follow all the comments on the issue no 62, you will know that there are others with the same issue I mentioned above. Tough luck for us I suppose.